# Amzon Copy Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to add the encoding shortcut to the [Amazon Redshift Copy Command taken from here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html). The copy command is

```
 COPY Tier2.personloginactivity (PersonId,LoginDateTime,TimeSpentOnSite) FROM 's3://imdb-ftp-development/tier2.text.csv' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=dsdsdsdsdsdsd;aws_secret_access_key=dsdsdsdsdsds' 
delimiter ','  IGNOREHEADER 1 encoding 'UTF-8';
```

The encoding portion is giving me a error. Can u please help.

Comment: please edit the question and post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Per the doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html:

Valid values for file_encoding are as follows:
UTF8
UTF16
UTF16LE
UTF16BE

So you need to remove the dash.